# Invalid Column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Ad.Id, Newspaper, 
    (select Organization from JobOrganization where JobOrganization.Id = Ad.OrganizationId) as Organization,
    Ad.PublishDate, Ad.LastDate,Ad.Url, Job.Id as JobId,
    (select JobTitle from JobTitle where JobTitle.Id = Job.TitleId) as JobTitle1,
    QualificationId, ExpInYears, CategoryId
     FROM Ad inner join Job on Ad.Id = Job.AdId
     Where JobTitle1 Like @title or @title is null
     Order by
 case When @sortCol='PublishDate' and @sortDir='ASC' Then Ad.PublishDate End ASC,
 case When @sortCol='PublishDate' and @sortDir='DESC' Then Ad.PublishDate End DESC,
 case When @sortCol='LastDate' and @sortDir='ASC' Then Ad.LastDate End ASC,
 case When @sortCol='LastDate' and @sortDir='DESC' Then Ad.LastDate End DESC
```

Error: Invalid column name 'JobTitle1'.

I am using SQL-2008

Comment: Any particular reason you're using subqueries rather than `JOIN` s to get the `Organization` and `JobTitle` ? If you used `JOIN` s your problem would go away...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't use aliases in where clauses,

```
    SELECT Ad.Id, Newspaper, 
    (select Organization from JobOrganization where JobOrganization.Id = Ad.OrganizationId) as Organization,
    Ad.PublishDate, Ad.LastDate,Ad.Url, Job.Id as JobId,
    (select JobTitle from JobTitle where JobTitle.Id = Job.TitleId) as JobTitle1,
    QualificationId, ExpInYears, CategoryId
     FROM Ad inner join Job on Ad.Id = Job.AdId
     Where (select JobTitle from JobTitle where JobTitle.Id = Job.TitleId)Like @title or @title is null
     Order by
 case When @sortCol='PublishDate' and @sortDir='ASC' Then Ad.PublishDate End ASC,
 case When @sortCol='PublishDate' and @sortDir='DESC' Then Ad.PublishDate End DESC,
 case When @sortCol='LastDate' and @sortDir='ASC' Then Ad.LastDate End ASC,
 case When @sortCol='LastDate' and @sortDir='DESC' Then Ad.LastDate End DESC
```

So in that case I'm using View ..

Answer (score 1):

JobTitle1 reference name scope is missing here ( Where **JobTitle1** Like @title or @title is null ) ,
try like this `( Where Ad.JobTitle1 Like @title or @title is null )`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use aliases in the WHERE clause because the WHERE clause is evaluated before the SELECT clause.