# Order by is not working

Tags: sql-server

```
With Results as
(
    SELECT Top(100) percent ROW_NUMBER() over (Order by (select 1)) as RowNumber, 
    Ad.Date, Title
     FROM Ad inner join Job on Ad.Id = Job.AdId
     Order by
     case When @sortCol='Date' and @sortDir='ASC' Then Date End ASC,
     case When @sortCol='Date' and @sortDir='DESC' Then Date End DESC
)
Select * from Results
Where RowNumber BETWEEN @FirstRow AND @LastRow
 END
```

Whatever is passed in @sortDir and @sortCol it does not work.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to don't delete questions when you have response and i'will help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568723/invalid-column-name/4568788#4568788

Comment: First thought - shouldn't your order by clause be on the "SELECT * FROM Results" query?

Comment: Yes I tried that but then paging does not work as expected as Row_Number is based on order by.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the result of `ROW_NUMBER() over (Order by (select 1))` to be well defined. Even if it appears to give correct results in simple tests, I wouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the `order by` clause to the `Row_Number` argument list could solve your problem.

`Order by` in `with` clause is not permitted.

Comment: How to get total count of Results into an output parameter?

Comment: Nothing in my mind, except the extra select @count = count(*) :-(